# insert stored procedure output value as one of the column value in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, insert, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to insert multiple lines of data from excel into oracle database with auto-created object_ID (which should be calculated from stored procedure).

I have a stored procedure called - get_objectid (diff output depends on code)
and other details are ;;

table : sample (object_id, code, name)
Values : object_id -> get from stored procedure
         code & name -> from excel data

How can i call stored procedure in this case for inserting object_id column?

WIll wait for your advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to split the load to a two-step process.

create a temporary table that includes only the data from the excel file. Load the data from excel without any modification to the temporary table.
The advantage of it is that you can review the data before actually inserting it that way. You can make sure the excel data appears as you expect.

Now you have a table within Oracle that has the excel data, and a table with the "final" data (the target table).
load from one to the other using:

```
INSERT INTO SAMPLE SELECT get_objectid(object_id), code, name from TMP_SELECT
```

good luck